# Having difficulty calling a method

Tags: java, methods, method-call

I have a feeling that the answer's right under my nose, but my n00b-ness to Java has me chasing my tail.  First part, I'm suppose to ask a user to in put two strings, compare them, and state the number of characters in the first string.  Second part, I'm suppose to ask the user to enter a position bearing in mind that the first character starts at zero, and then the code's suppose to state the character that is at that position.

I think my code for the first part is pretty clean, but what I need help on is the second part.  I've written the method at the bottom, but now I don't know how to call it.  I keep getting an error message in the compiler.  I also haven't gotten a chance to actually test the method because of that error, so if you see anything wrong with that, any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringCode1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    String string1, string2;
    int pos;

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter first string: ");
        string1 = stdin.next();
        System.out.print("Enter second string: ");
        string2 = stdin.next();

        if (string1.compareTo(string2) > 0)
    {
       System.out.println(string1 + " is less than " + string2);
    }
        else if (string1.compareTo(string2) == 0)
    {
       System.out.println(string1 + " is equal to " + string2);
    }
        else if (string1.compareTo(string2) < 0)
    {
       System.out.println(string1 + " is greater than " + string2);
    }
    System.out.print("Number of characters in " + string1 + " is " );       

    System.out.println(string1.length() );

    String = showChar();
   }

   public static char showChar(String string1, int pos)
   {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter position noting first character is at 0: ");
    string1 = stdin.nextLine();
    pos = stdin.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Character at position" + pos + "in " + string1); 
    System.out.print("is: "); 
    System.out.println(string1.charAt(pos));

   }  
  }
```

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Your code's indentation is "all over the place like a mad woman's knitting" ... as as my old science teacher would say (RIP AAC).  If you want people to treat your code / Questions seriously, you need to pay attention to the style.

Answer (score 1):

```
String = showChar();
```

In the above line, you are trying to assign to a type, which is an invalid expression. Additionally, your method `showChar` requires two arguments and you're trying to call it with none.

One more error is that `showChar` has a return type of `char` but no `return` statement. Either make it a `void` method, or have it `return` something (presumably `string1.charAt(pos)`).

So, you'll have to find what the argument for `showChar` should be and then, if the value of `showChar` is supposed to return a `char`, assign it to a variable of its type, like so:

```
char c = showChar(string1, yourIndex);
```

Or, if it's going to be `void`:

```
showChar(string1, yourIndex);
```

...where `yourIndex` is the value you want to pass for the `pos` parameter in `showCar`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your showChar function as below:

```
public static void showChar()
{
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter position noting first character is at 0: ");
    String string1 = stdin.nextLine();
    int pos = stdin.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Character at position" + pos + "in " + string1); 
    System.out.print("is: "); 
    System.out.println(string1.charAt(pos));

}
```

And call it with `showChar();`

Comment: You can refer to Theodoros' explanation.